# Exceeded maximum execution time in Google Apps Script to retrieve users name and email address from email domain

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have this code. I set a time trigger to retrieve every employee's names, email address from the email domain, assign  a primary key to it and write it on spreadsheet. I did that for attendance system. But when the execution time is greater than 5 minutes, I can't retrieve the whole employees name and email address from the email domain. 
What can I do? 
Please help.
 Thank you!

```
function primarykeyrecord(){
 var lastval;
 var sheet=getData();
 var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
 lastval=data[data.length-1][0]; 
  if(lastval !== "primarykeyvalue"){
    lastval=lastval+1;
   }
  else {
     lastval=1;
  }
 // Logger.log( lastval);
  return lastval;
}

// list all the user from the  domain
function listAllUsers() {
  var pageToken, page;
  var today =methodtimenow();
  do {
    page = AdminDirectory.Users.list({
      domain: '',
      //orderBy: 'givenName',
      maxResults: 300,
      pageToken: pageToken
    });
     users = page.users;
    userslength=users.length; // the number of user from the email domain 
    if (users) {
      for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        var user = users[i];
        var sheet = getData();
        var lastval=primarykeyrecord();

        var range = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, 4);
        var values = [[lastval,today,user.primaryEmail,user.name.fullName ]];
        range.setValues(values);
      }
    } else {
      Logger.log('No users found.');
    }
    pageToken = page.nextPageToken;
  } while (pageToken);

//Logger.log(values);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your script is timing out is, you are recursively calling setValues() and getValue(). Both are resource intensive process and should be used sparingly as possible, use batch updating instead.

The below code gets all the user data in values array and adds the array in one go at the end.

```
 function listAllUsers() {
          var pageToken, page;
          var today =methodtimenow();
          var lastval=primarykeyrecord(); //Access the last value once and then keep adding one
          var values = []   //Create empty array
  do {
        page = AdminDirectory.Users.list({
          domain: '',
          //orderBy: 'givenName',
          maxResults: 300,
          pageToken: pageToken
        });
         users = page.users;
        userslength=users.length; // the number of user from the email domain 
        if (users) {
          // And all the user data to values array
          for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
            var user = users[i];
            var temp = [lastval,today,user.primaryEmail,user.name.fullName ];
            values.push(temp)
            lastval++;                //Increase key value by one
          }
        } else {
          Logger.log('No users found.');
        }
        pageToken = page.nextPageToken;
      } while (pageToken);
    var sheet = getData();
    var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow()
    var range = sheet.getRange(lastRow+1, 1, values.length, 4);
    range.setValues(values);
    //Logger.log(values);
    }
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you! But I got an error at range.setValues(values) line which is "Incorrect range height, was 282 but should be 3276".

Comment: for(var i=data.length-1 ; i>= 0; i--) {
        var date = new Date(data[i].dateattend);
}

I have this loop many places in my program. Does it make my system slow? How can I replace it by other code?